# The difference between Atmel ATmega16u2-MU and -MUR

Tags: avr, atmel

What is the difference between ATMEGA16U2-MU and ATMEGA16U2-MUR?

Atmel lists these 2 codes in the table on their product page but I could not find any explanation in the datasheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Digikey: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ATMEGA16U2-MUR/ATMEGA16U2-MURCT-ND/2477167 the "MU" parts are packaged in a tray while the "MUR" parts come in Tape-and-Reel (or cut tape). Refer to the bottom right of the linked page under "Alternate Package".